# Vimscript: Trigger when cursor moved between lines

Tags: vim, autocmd

I need a autocmd trigger to use when the cursor moves between lines.

Now I'm using:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * call MyFunc()
```

With it, MyFunc is executed in each cursor movement, but I need a trigger only when cursor move up or down (not right and left)

EDIT:

Checking the cursor line with the last recorded line works for me.

```
if line(".") != s:recordedLine
 let s:recordedLine = line(".")
 ....
```

Comment: save current line number in a var, with CursorMoved triggered, compare new line number with the var, to decide if it was moved to a different line?

Comment: Here is an article http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Timer_to_execute_commands_periodically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you are trying to do. You likely will need to call `MyFunc()` every time, but put a condition in the function to decide whether or not to do the action. Perhaps you could use `getchar()` to figure out if <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> was pressed. Or perhaps you can record the current line number (`let line=getline('.')`)and compare it with the previous line number.

Comment: getchar() is not a good idea, what about `(, ), {, }, 'm, '[`

Comment: True enough. There are many ways to jump one or multiple lines. The line number comparison would be a better approach.